# How to Create A TelnetClient Connection pooling

Tags: java, sockets, connection, inputstream, connection-pooling

> Blockquote

I am trying to implement cusotm connection pooling for TelnetClient connections but getting some challenge......

Step 1 : I have created a connection successfully
Step 2 : I have tried to execute a command using above connection 
successfully
Step 3: but with the same connection as I tried to execute another command 
than I am getting bothe the response(step 2 & step 3) response and It's 
seems as I am using the same connection and I did not closed it so the data
are present in connection input & output streams.

Can be reset inputSteam of the connection so that I can only have the 
current command resposne in it.

Is there is anyother opensource api for TelnetClient connection pooling?

I dont have much experience in network and socket programming any help 
would be highly appreciate!!

> Blockquote

```
 //Method is used to create a connection 
 private TelnetClient createTelnetConnection() throws SocketException, 
IOException {
    TelnetClient telnetConnection = new TelnetClient();
    telnetConnection.connect(127.0.0.1, 6300);
    telnetConnection.setConnectTimeout(240000);
    telnetConnection.setSoTimeout(300000);
    return telnetConnection;
```

}

```
//This method is used to execute command using connection
public String executeCommand(String command, TelnetClient connection) throws InterruptedException,
    IOException {
    OutputStream outputstream = null;
    InputStream inputstream = null;
    String response = "";

    outputstream = connection.getOutputStream();
    outputstream.write(command.getBytes());
    outputstream.flush();

    inputstream = connection.getInputStream();

    response = getStringFromInputStream(inputstream);
    return response;
```

}

```
  private String getStringFromInputStream(InputStream inputStream) throws 
   IOException {
      BufferedReader bufferReader = null;
      StringBuilder responseString = new StringBuilder();
      String line;
      bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
      String response = null;
      while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
        responseString.append(line);
        break;

    }
    return responseString.toString();
 }
```

Comment: Why downvote ?  just mention the reason in comment.

Comment: which Tcp client you are using to make connection and to find out the solution.

Comment: I am using org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient .